# Not able to read a cookie with ":" in the cookie name in java

Tags: servlets, cookies

I have a cookie with the name having colon in the name of the cookie.

ex: abcd:1=someVAlueOfCookies

I'm not getting this cookie in request.getCookies() of java servlet request.

Can't we have the cookie name with ":" in it.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cookie JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#Cookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> The name must conform to RFC 2109.

[RFC2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.1):

> 4.1  Syntax:  General

> The two state management headers, Set-Cookie and Cookie, have common
> syntactic properties involving attribute-value pairs.  The following
> grammar uses the notation, and tokens DIGIT (decimal digits) and
> token (informally, a sequence of non-special, non-white space
> characters) from the HTTP/1.1 specification [RFC 2068] to describe
> their syntax.

> ```
> av-pairs        =       av-pair *(";" av-pair)
> ```

```
av-pair         =       attr ["=" value]        ; optional value
attr            =       token
value           =       word
word            =       token | quoted-string
```

[RFC2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-2.2):

> ```
> token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or tspecials>
> ```

```
tspecials      = "(" | ")" | "<" | ">" | "@"
                     | "," | ";" | ":" | "\" | <">
                     | "/" | "[" | "]" | "?" | "="
                     | "{" | "}" | SP | HT
```

So, yes, Java's cookie names can't have colons. There are newer cookie specs, where not using colons is a recommendation, not an obligation, but Java seems to conform to this older standard.